# How can I block a specific file (eg:PDF) in a library in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, library, pdf, irm

I'm need to block a specific file format in a library of SharePoint online site (o365). I have activated RMS feature in admin & in Admin-> sharepoint-> settings too.

What's the next step or procedure?

Or is there a feature or method where I can allow the users to add only documents or Pdf file format ?

Comment: Do you want people to stop saving a certain format, or open files (in that format) that happen to be there already.

Comment: They are not allowed to upload other formats, except documents or pdf (depending upon the situation). For eg: in one library only pdf and in another library only documents.

Answer (score 4):

There is no OOTB facility with SharePoint Online to restrict specific file extensions in SharePoint Online. The only ways are:

- Create an event handler which will check the file extension.
- Create a workflow for the same.

Answer (score 2):

I had a look around and can't see any indication that this is editable - seems like another thing MS hide from us.

From looking at the IRM options on a library it doesn't seem like blocking certain file types is an option, just that you can block any non-IRM compatible files being uploaded.

My suggestion would be a workflow that auto-runs on each item and if it doesn't match the given type, auto-deletes the document. Little bit clunky but it would do the job, just keep an eye on resource usage if you're dealing with a ton of documents.