# With SharePoint Online, how can I block certain file types from being uploaded?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

In Office 365 SharePoint Online, it there a way through the web interface or PowerShell to block users from uploading certain file types? We would like to block .doc and `.xls` files as users should now only be using `.docx` and `.xlsx` files.  Another post suggested using a *Event Receiver* but this seemed too complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No OOTB way to configure these settings, as you mentioned you have to create either event receiver or Workflow to block the file types for the SharePoint sites.

But there is a way for onedrive where you can restrict the certain files types from syncing.  You can use [Set-SPOTenantSyncClientRestriction](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/Set-SPOTenantSyncClientRestriction?view=sharepoint-ps):

```
Set-SPOTenantSyncClientRestriction  -ExcludedFileExtensions "ppt;doc;xls"
```

On Side note, you can register your voice here, already reported to MSFT. [Custom restrictions of file types that user can upload to a document library.](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/12498615-custom-restrictions-of-file-types-that-user-can-up#%7Btoggle_previous_statuses%7D)

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOB way to do it. The easiest way would be to create a workflow that would delete the file automatically based on the extensions.

This question was already [answered here.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/192222/how-can-i-block-a-specific-file-egpdf-in-a-library-in-sharepoint-online)

Answer (score 1):

There is no OOB solution for this , the best option is to create a event receiver and triggers on item adding . If you think the option is much complicated , you can create a simple SharePoint Designer workflow .

1. [Rename the file from a workflow](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/12/sharepoint-workflow-power-pack-user.html) .
2. Create a workflow in SharePoint designer that moves non `.docx` or `.xlsx` files to another library . See an example :http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/sharepoint-designer-workflow-move-document-one-library-next.htm .